# What the CADisplayLink's timestamp actually is?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, rendering, cadisplaylink

I've been playing with functionality of `CADisplayLink` to programmatically monitor rendering performance in an iOS app. Also spent quite some time in Instruments, of course, but curious of what it looks like in the field and for *specific* screens in the app.

The documentation says that a `CADisplayLink` timer object

> allows your app to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.

which makes me expect that the provided selector is called somewhat close to `vsync` events emitted by the underlying hardware. Also, the `timestamp` property is defined as follows:

> The time interval that represents when the last frame displayed.

So I just use the two successive callbacks to figure out the on-screen duration of the frame and decide if there was a hitch or not, like so:

```
@objc private func handleDisplayUpdate(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    defer { cachedTimestamp = displayLink.timestamp }
    guard let cachedTimestamp = cachedTimestamp else { return }
    let frameTime = displayLink.timestamp - cachedTimestamp
    if frameTime > aThreshold {
      // do some lightweight logging
    }
}
```

By using `CACurrentMediaTime()` call I can see that the handler is called pretty close to what the latest `timestamp` holds, so it is 1ms-ish behind the recent frame update. However the `frameTime` intervals are not always a multiple of 16.67ms (assuming the device renders @60fps): while scrolling I can observe the numbers being e.g. 25ms or 43ms.

Given that frames are swapped onto the display at `vsync` points in time only, does the above mean that the `timestamp` property actually represents something else in the whole render loop?

Comment: Which device are you running on?  Remember that some iPhones have a variable refresh rate to save battery.

Comment: Thanks, Paulw11 , that is a good point indeed. iPhone 7 is the device running iOS 15.7.1, but since it is plugged in for debugging I would not expect lowering of the refresh rate. And if I check the effective refresh rate using the recommended `targetTimestamp - timestamp` I can see it is constantly at 60fps

Comment: Yeah, an iPhone 7 does not have variable refresh rate display.

Comment: Great question. I can only speculate here, but first off note that technically CVDisplayLink (and presumably CADisplayLink) are not guaranteed to be called at start of a vsync, see https://thume.ca/2017/12/09/cvdisplaylink-doesnt-link-to-your-display/ for more information. But that aside, since the targetTimestamp is the predicted time while `timestamp` was the actual realized time, it's quite possible that the predictions don't match reality. See for instance the wayland present protocol which has a similar notion

Comment: >When the final realized presentation time is available, e.g. after a framebuffer flip completes, the requested presentation_feedback.presented events are sent. The final presentation time can differ from the compositor's predicted display update time and the update's target time, especially when the compositor misses its target vertical blanking period.